# Unable to compile class for JSP and cannot convert from String to boolean when I use array to make a navbar

Tags: arrays, jsp, while-loop

I have an idea to create a navigation bar with **Arrays** and looping it with **While**.

first, I make a variable on my jsp file like this:

```
<%
int i, j;
i = 0;
j = 0;

String[][] NavMenu = new String[6][5];
NavMenu[0][0] = "Company Profile";
NavMenu[1][0] = "Product";
NavMenu[2][0] = "Marketing Plan";
NavMenu[3][0] = "News";
NavMenu[3][1] = "Event";
NavMenu[3][2] = "Promo";
NavMenu[3][3] = "Artikel";
NavMenu[3][4] = "Testimony";
NavMenu[4][0] = "Merchandise";
NavMenu[5][0] = "Job Vacancies";

String[][] NavLink = new String[6][5];
NavLink[0][0] = "company-profile-infiny-niaga-abadi.html";
NavLink[1][0] = "product.html";
NavLink[2][0] = "marketing-plan.html";
NavLink[3][0] = "#";
NavLink[3][1] = "news/event.html";
NavLink[3][2] = "news/promo.html";
NavLink[3][3] = "news/article.html";
NavLink[3][4] = "news/testimony.html";
NavLink[4][0] = "merchandise.html";
NavLink[5][0] = "job-vacancies.html";
%>
```

The **NavMenu** is a text for Navbar menu, and **NavLink** is a link for Navbar menu.

and then, I make my navbar like this:

```
<%
while (NavMenu[i][0]) { //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean
    j = 1;

    //IF MENU HAVE A DROPDOWN
    if(NavMenu[i][1]){ //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean
        if(NavMenu[i][0] == ActivePage) { %>
            <li class="active dropdown">
        <% } else { %>
            <li class="dropdown">
        <% } %>

        <a href="<%= NavLink[i][0] %>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%=NavMenu[i][0]%> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <%
        while(NavMenu[i][j]) { //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean %>
            <li>
                <a href="<%= NavLink[i][j]%>"><%= NavMenu[i][j]%></a>
            </li>
            <% j++;
        } %>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <% 
    //IF MENU DO NOT HAVE A DROPDOWN
    } else {
        if(NavMenu[i][0] == ActivePage){ %>
            <li class="active"><a href="<%= NavLink[i][0]%>"><%= NavMenu[i][0] %></a></li>
        <% } else {%>
            <li><a href="<%= NavLink[i][0] %>"><%= NavMenu[i][0] %></a></li>
        <%}
    }
    i++;
    j=0;
}
%>
```

How to solve this Problem? I have no idea what should I do to make this working.

Comment: your while syntax is false.In while you pass a condotion

Comment: First of all you must learn about programming main subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is not like javascript, you can not use string as condition, In java the condition must be in `boolean`. you can use a `for` loop to iterate over the `String` array and do your logic

```
<%


String[][] NavMenu = new String[6][5];
NavMenu[0][0] = "Company Profile";
NavMenu[1][0] = "Product";
NavMenu[2][0] = "Marketing Plan";
NavMenu[3][0] = "News";
NavMenu[3][1] = "Event";
NavMenu[3][2] = "Promo";
NavMenu[3][3] = "Artikel";
NavMenu[3][4] = "Testimony";
NavMenu[4][0] = "Merchandise";
NavMenu[5][0] = "Job Vacancies";

String[][] NavLink = new String[6][5];
NavLink[0][0] = "company-profile-infiny-niaga-abadi.html";
NavLink[1][0] = "product.html";
NavLink[2][0] = "marketing-plan.html";
NavLink[3][0] = "#";
NavLink[3][1] = "news/event.html";
NavLink[3][2] = "news/promo.html";
NavLink[3][3] = "news/article.html";
NavLink[3][4] = "news/testimony.html";
NavLink[4][0] = "merchandise.html";
NavLink[5][0] = "job-vacancies.html";
%>

<%
for (int i=0; i<NavMenu.length; i++) { //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean

    String navMenuValue = NavMenu[i][0];

    //IF MENU HAVE A DROPDOWN
    if(NavMenu[i].length > 1){ //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean
        if(NavMenu[i][0].equals("ActivePage")) { %>
            <li class="active dropdown">
        <% } else { %>
            <li class="dropdown">
        <% } %>

        <a href="<%= NavLink[i][0] %>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%=NavMenu[i][0]%> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <%
        for(int j=0;j<NavMenu[i].length;j++) { //ERROR ON HERE: cannot convert from String to boolean %>
            <li>
                <a href="<%= NavLink[i][j]%>"><%= NavMenu[i][j]%></a>
            </li>
            <% 
        } %>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <% 
    //IF MENU DO NOT HAVE A DROPDOWN
    } else {
        if(NavMenu[i][0].equals("ActivePage")){ %>
            <li class="active"><a href="<%= NavLink[i][0]%>"><%= NavMenu[i][0] %></a></li>
        <% } else {%>
            <li><a href="<%= NavLink[i][0] %>"><%= NavMenu[i][0] %></a></li>
        <%}
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: I ever try with `for` loop. It's still not works. 

Did you know how to convert String into boolean?

Comment: @Onixion Check my updated answer, this is how you have to iterate a string array. To convert a string to boolean using a null check will be enough